# Desktop shortcut with Default database for SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2008

I am working on 5 different development projects.

Each of them have a C# solution, and a different database to connect to.

Each C# solution has a desktop shortcut, pointing to the right / different sources.

I would like to have something like that for the databases.

So when I click a shortcut on my desktop, **each of those 5 shortcuts would open a different database**, and maybe ask for my credentials. (I wouldn't mind if they didn't)

I am not even sure what exactly should I search for, is the "Solution" the same as in Visual Studio, and I can use the ssms solution, or there is something else I need to use?

I am using 2008 R2.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With some help, I was able to figure out how to make this work.

I tested it, and it looks fine, I love it !

Pic 1: see the parameters, the ssms.exe can get

Pic 2: see my shortcut on the desktop, and in the "Target" field, see my parameters

[image: this is how you do it]